# How do I add a custom text input for the customer

Tags: paypal, simplecart

I need help adding a way for a customer to specify a custom design they want on a product. For example the text they want printed on a shirt. If I'm correct it should be something like:
type=text, value="What they wanted printed.", class="Custom Design", however I still need help.

I'd then want it to tell me what they wanted on their shirt in the PayPal order so I could print it. If possible I'd also like their 'custom input' for that item displayed in the cart columns, but this isn't necessary.

I know this is a lot but I'd seriously appreciate it,
thanks,
George.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this style:

```
input {
border: 5px solid white; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 
  inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
-moz-box-shadow: 
  inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
box-shadow: 
  inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
padding: 15px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
```

}